# Get variable number of parameters in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, parameters, anonymous

I'm parsing an XML document with JS, changing to lower case every first letter of the tags names. I.E. `<MyTagName></MyTagName>` will become `<myTagName></myTagName>`, very simple and everything works fine. I'm using a regex to find all the tags and replacing the name with the camel version, like this:

```
regex = /(<)(\/){0,1}([A-Z]*)(\/){0,1}(>)/ig;

result = result.replace(regex, function(s, m0, m1, m2, m3, m4){
    return m0 + (m1 ? m1 : "") + camelNotation(m2) + (m3 ? m3 : "") + m4;
});
```

My question is: is there a way to get some of the parameters in the anonymous function which is the second argument of my `replace` function in a more dynamic way, like an array? Something like

```
result = result.replace(regex, function(s, param[]){
    return param[0] + (param[1]? param[1] : "") + camelNotation(param[2]) + (param[3] ? param[3] : "") + param[4];
});
```

I may use `arguments[i]`, but I would like to know if I can customize my parameters in the function signature.

Thank you

Comment: why don't you just pass an array and check the length of the array?

Comment: *"I may use `arguments[i]`, but I would like to know if I can customize my parameters in the function signature."* "customize" how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often use the following simple higher-order function:

```
splat = function(fun, thisp) {
    return function() { return fun.call(thisp, [].slice.call(arguments)) }
}
```

e.g.

```
"a1b2c3d4e5f6".replace(/(\D)(\d)/g, splat(function(a) {
    return a[1].toUpperCase() + (++a[2]);
}))
```

Comment: I choosed your answer because of the soft impact the addition of the splat() function has on the code, but other answers were also valid. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the arguments inside the body of the function like so:

```
result = result.replace(regex, function(s, /*params...*/){
  // get real array without the first argument
  var params = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
  ...
});
```

> I may use arguments[i], but I would like to know if I can customize my
>   parameters in the function signature.

You can use `arguments` or get the arguments you want into an array, but other than that there's no alternative syntax (yet, it's coming soon). The convention for "rest params" is to annotate them as a comment.

Comment: @ OP: Note that you only have to do the `slice` thing if you don't want to use `arguments[1]`, `arguments[2]`, etc., directly.

Comment: OP: I might've misread your question. Yes, you can use `arguments` or get the arguments you want into an array, but other than that there's no alternative syntax. The convention for "rest params" is to annotate them as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a forwarding function to package up the arguments into an array:

```
result.replace(regex, function(s) {
    return realFunction(s, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
});
```

where `realFunction` has the signature `function(s, params)` (it can of course be defined and called inline if you prefer). See the documentation on [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) for info on how this works.